# Gitlab Pipeline fails when another pipeline starts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When we commit to a branch in a repo, the gitlab pipeline starts.
Then if another commit to the same repo starts, on another branch or the same. It cancels the initial pipeline.

Is there a setting to allow both to run together?
Or a setting to not make them cancel when another one starts?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the Left Panel of your GitLab project.

Settings -> CI/CD -> General Pipelines: uncheck "Auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines".